# проблема с подключением (include) файлов

Tags: php, include, require

Есть наследуемый файл `small.php`, который я приинклюдил в другом файле (`mid.php`). Подключаю я  `mid.php` в `big.php` и код отрабатывает. Но отрабатывает, если `big.php` находится в той же папке.

Использовал полный путь к файлу - не помогло. Так же не подходит вариант с `"../"`. Странную особенность заметил - подняться в вверх на одну папку `"../"` - подымает на две.

```
include_path='.:'
```

Comment: вот уж про полный путь не верю. А как у вас файлы расположены? логично, что все работает, когда в одной папке. А цель то какая?

Comment: Структуру расположения файлов от корня сайта можно?

Comment: Решаю проблему так( показаны правильные путя)
`код`
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../engine/loger.php');
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../CONFIG/config.php');
`код`
@teran цель - устранить глюк подключения из папкок второго и глубже уровней,когда файлы которые находятся рядом,по разному реагируют на подключенный файл нулевого уровня